# How do I get a Radeon RX 550 working with OpenCL on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, radeon, amdgpu-pro

When I follow the official guide for installing the AMDGPU-Pro drivers (I've tried both the 17.30 and the very recent 17.40 releases) everything seems to work but `clinfo` still returns

```
Number of platforms 0
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just spent the whole day on this too - I couldn't find any working instructions so here's what I came up with for AMD Radeon RX 580 on Ubuntu 16.04 system with no graphical desktop, installed over SSH:

*Assume a fresh Ubuntu install system*

1. Get the AMD APP SDK from [here](https://developer.amd.com/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/) - Download, Unpack and then use `sudo` to run the install script.
2. Download the most recent linux driver (17.50 at time of writing this answer) from [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux), extract the `.xz` file using `tar Jxvf <filename>` and `cd` into the directory created after extracting the `.xz` file.
3. Now run the installer with `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=legacy -y
   ```
4. Reboot
5. Run `clinfo` again and you should see that you now have OpenCL **1.2** support:

   ```
   $ clinfo|grep OpenCL

   Platform Version:               OpenCL 2.1 AMD-APP (2527.3)
   Execute OpenCL kernels:         Yes
   Device OpenCL C version:        OpenCL C 1.2
   Version:                        OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (2527.3)
   ```

The reason for this is that specifying `--legacy` pulls in `opencl-amdgpu-pro-icd` which is not normally installed.

I think this is because the latest drivers want to do things with ROCm:
https://rocm.github.io/ROCmInstall.html

On my own rig, ROCm is unusable because I've got PCI-e 1x slots with risers and a basic Pentium CPU instead of an i7. You check that ROCm was disabled like this:

```
$ dmesg |grep atomic
[4.885958] kfd kfd: skipped device 1002:67df, PCI rejects atomics
```

So I guess this is why I had to do *legacy* to get OpenCL working at all.

I'm not sure what the pros/cons are of OpenCL 1.2 vs OpenCL 2.0 vs ROCm, or even if the ROCm driver presents as OpenCL 2.0 externally - would be great if someone with more insight could comment.

Comment: This is an old answer.. you can use risers now apparently :) In the meantime I gave up and bought windows 10

Comment: Fantastic answer. This + using an older kernel (4.18) was the only thing which would get my AMD RX480 working on Ubuntu 18.04. Fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL failed because I had issues building the DKMS module, due to my kernel.

Upgrading my kernel to the following version got clinfo reporting OpenCL support on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15.11/

linux-headers-4.15.11-041511_4.15.11-041511.201803190530_all.deb

linux-headers-4.15.11-041511-generic_4.15.11-041511.201803190530_amd64.deb

linux-image-4.15.11-041511-generic_4.15.11-041511.201803190530_amd64.deb

```
clinfo|grep OpenCL
  Platform Version          OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (2482.3)
  Device Version            OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (2482.3)
  Device OpenCL C Version   OpenCL C 1.2 
    Run OpenCL kernels      Yes
```