# AMD RX 470 OpenCL not working Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 with amdgpu-pro 18.50

Tags: drivers, opencl, amdgpu-pro

I have spent a lot of time trying to get OpenCL to work on my RX 470. My goal is to run this server as a Folding@Home client. I have read guides like: [How do I get a Radeon RX 550 working with OpenCL on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977869/how-do-i-get-a-radeon-rx-550-working-with-opencl-on-ubuntu-16-04)
AMD APP SDK no longer exists and some posts from other forums says that it is no longer needed too.
My system runs Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 and I have ran

```
sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=legacy -y
```

This however doesn't work gives me this:

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu-lib32 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:2.4.95-708488)
                Depends: libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (= 1:2.4.95-708488)
                Depends: libllvm7.0-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:7.0-708488)
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 (= 1.15.0-708488)
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 (= 1.15.0-708488)
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-egl1:i386 (= 1.15.0-708488)
                Depends: libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488)
                Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488)
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488)
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488)
                Depends: libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488)
                Depends: libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488)
                Depends: libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488)
                Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488)
                Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488)
                Depends: libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488)
                Depends: mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488)
                Depends: mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (= 1:18.2.0-708488)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is probably because I don't use x11 or wayland since the server is running without any desktop environment. Using the headless option does work. So I used this instead:

```
sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=legacy -y --headless
```

After a reboot, I used clinfo to check if openCL is working but all I get is this:

```
Number of platforms                               0
```

What should I do?